# Pregmatch explanation

Tags: php, regex

I am not sure to get what is this code trying to do, please help me to understand :

```
if(preg_match('#^.{1,5}@(gmail|yahoo|aol|hotmail|msn|ymail)#i',$email)) return false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/g3ZncjpH-gT7PvqU)

**Regex autopsy**:

```
#^.{1,5}@(gmail|yahoo|aol|hotmail|msn|ymail)#i
```

- `#` - *This is the delimiter - you need one of these at the start and the end, and it doesn't have to be `#` (it just has to match at the end as well). The most common delimiter is a forward slash (`/`) (why the `i` is there I'll get to)*
- `^` - *The next part of the regex MUST match the start of the string - nothing can come before it*
- `.{1,5}` - *Any character (`.`) matched 1 to 5 times*
- `@` - *A literal `@` character*
- `(gmail|yahoo|aol|hotmail|msn|ymail)` - *Either of literal strings `gmail` or `yahoo` or `aol` or `hotmail` or `msn` or `ymail`*
- `#` - *The end delimiter*
- `i` - *This is an "in-case-sensitive" modifier which means we'll also match `MSN`/`gMail`/`YAhoO`*

So in short this *doesn't* match:

> `myemail@gmail.com` (*we have 6 characters before the `@` sign*)
>   `foo@bar.com` (*none of the listed domains are present*)

However, it *does* match:

> `12345@gmail.dk`
>   `!"#¤%@MSN.COM` (*`.` is ANY symbol*)
>   `a@hotmail.de`
>   `foo@yahoo-email-sucks.com` (*because we don't match what comes AFTER "yahoo"*)

Comment: @pollux1er You might want to check the edits to see what it matches as well - that might be helpful :)

Comment: @Downvote - why? This is perfectly correct information.

Answer (score -1):

^ assert position at start of the string
.{1,5} matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: Between 1 and 5 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
@ matches the character @ literally
1st Capturing group (gmail|yahoo|aol|hotmail|msn|ymail)
1st Alternative: gmail
gmail matches the characters gmail literally (case insensitive)
2nd Alternative: yahoo
yahoo matches the characters yahoo literally (case insensitive)
3rd Alternative: aol
aol matches the characters aol literally (case insensitive)
4th Alternative: hotmail
hotmail matches the characters hotmail literally (case insensitive)
5th Alternative: msn
msn matches the characters msn literally (case insensitive)
6th Alternative: ymail
ymail matches the characters ymail literally (case insensitive)
i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])

Comment: [If you're just going to simply copy paste from Regex101, you might as well link to it](http://regex101.com/r/jA6hC8)